# Can I use Hadoop 2.0.0-cdh4.5.0 with Cassandra 2.0.5?

Tags: hadoop, cassandra, cloudera

I am trying to use Hadoop 2.0 (specifically the Cloudera 4.5 distribution) with a Cassandra 2.0.4 database.  After struggling through a bunch of issues (e.g. making sure Hadoop was running with the 1.7 jdk) I am stuck on this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Found interface org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobContext, but class was expected
    at org.apache.cassandra.hadoop.AbstractColumnFamilyInputFormat.getSplits(AbstractColumnFamilyInputFormat.java:120)
```

Is this expected to work?  Should I try the Cloudera 5.0 beta distro?  Any other ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Until very recently Cassandra didn't have support for the YARN map reduce interfaces, it only supported the older (0.21/1.x) hadoop interfaces. A patch was just accepted into Cassandra that should fix this (issue [CASSANDRA-5201](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-5201)). It will be available when 2.0.6 is released.

Comment: Do you know when 2.0.6 is expected to be released?  Would you recommend getting the current 2.1 devel snapshot for use with hadoop, and pointing it at a 2.0.4 database instance?